# WPF retrieving image path as string

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a ListView with few image items. I want to get the item path (image) when its is clicked in a string and get it into a database as VALUES. Thank you.

XML

```
<ListView  x:Name="LvImagini" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="215,299,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
    <ListViewItem>
        <Image Source="/imagini/1.png" Width="170" Height="180"/>
    </ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>
        <Image Source="/imagini/2.png" Width="170" Height="180"/>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Button Function

```
private void btnRegSucces_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try 
        {
            con.Open();
            String query = "INSERT into jucatori(utilizator,password) VALUES('" + tbxUtilizator.Text + "','" + tbxParola.Password + "')";

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            //String geo = LvImagini.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            LabelError.Content = "E R O A R E!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're having troubles with getting the source property from the selected image, rather than the actual database query.

```
    private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var source= ((Image)((ListViewItem)sender).Content).Source;
    }
```

XAML

```
        <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="257" Margin="135,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322">
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Source="\imagini\1.jpg" Width="170" Height="180"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Image Source="\imagini\2.jpg" Width="170" Height="180"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the source from the XAML markup is not that easy given that it is converted to a pack URI behind the scenes but something like this should work:

```
ListViewItem selectedItem = LvImagini.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;
Image image = selectedItem.Content as Image;
string source = image.Source.ToString();
string path = source.Substring(source.IndexOf("pack://application:,,,/") + 23);
```